# ValueError: Could not guess the value column! Please hand it to the function as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection, feature-extraction, dataframe

I'm using the [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/introduction.html) library to extract features on my data but I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: Could not guess the value column! Please hand it to the function as an argument.
```

In the [source code for tsfresh feature extraction](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tsfresh/feature_extraction/data.) I see:

```
def _get_value_columns(df, *other_columns):
    value_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col not in other_columns]

    if len(value_columns) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Could not guess the value column! Please hand it to the function as an argument.")

    return value_columns
```

Which seems to indicate that my column length is 0 but when I print the length of my column, I see it is 64.

```
print(len(df.temperature))
```

```
[64 rows x 1 columns]
64
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
from tsfresh import extract_features, extract_relevant_features, select_features
from tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions import impute

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=tempArray)
          
df.columns = ['temperature']
print(len(df.temperature))
extracted_features= extract_features(df, column_id='temperature')
impute(extracted_features)
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the output when you check the value of `df.columns`?

Comment: When I `print(df.columns)`, I get `Index(['temperature'], dtype='object')`